# Complex query Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

Hi I have a complex queries

```
SELECT distinct libelle_adresse from adresse 
where id_adresse in (select id_adresse from zone_adresse 
where fk_zone in (select id_zone from zone 
where id_arrondissement in (select id_arrondissement from arrondissement
where libelle_arrondissement="'.$_GET['arrondis'].'")))
```

I've used `$arrondis = $request->input('arrondis');`to get the "arrondis" parameter from URL and pass it to my Controller.

This my attempt

```
    $term = $request->term;

    $arrondis = $request->input('arrondis');

    $query1 = DB::table('arrondissement')
    ->select('id_arrondissement')
    ->where('libelle_arrondissement','=',$arrondis)
    ->get();

    $query2 = DB::table('zone');
    ->select('id_zone')
    ->where('id_arrondissement','=',$query1)
    ->get();

    $query3 = DB::table('zone_adresse');
    ->select('id_adresse')
    ->where('fk_zone','=',$query2)
    ->get();

    $queries = DB::table('adresse');
    ->where('id_adresse','=',$query3)
    ->where('libelle_adresse','like','%'.$term.'%')
    ->take(3)->get();
    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = ['id' => $query->id_adresse, 'value' => $query->libelle_adresse]; 
    }
    return response()->json($results);
```

I know that I get the error when I pass the "query(1/2/3) variable" in "where" but I couldn't find any solution

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why you didn't use join

Comment: my bad I forgot them. which one is easier to transform it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let try this

```
DB::table("adresse")
    ->whereIn("id_adresse", DB::table("zone_adresse")
       ->whereIn("fk_zone", DB::table("zone")
         ->whereIn("id_arrondissement", DB::table("arrondissement")
           ->where("libelle_arrondissement","=", $_GET['arrondis'])
           ->pluck("id_arrondissement")->toArray()
        )
         ->pluck("id_zone")->toArray()
    )->pluck("id_adresse")->toArray())
    ->distinct()
    ->select("libelle_adresse as value, id_adresse as id")
    ->where('libelle_adresse', 'like', '%'.$term.'%') 
    ->get();
```

This will help you put all your query into one. But this looks ugly(will solve the problem though). The best i would recommend is to use **Eloquent**

Comment: I want to add this  " where->('libelle_adresse', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')  "  

Where shoud i put it ? before plunk or after ?

Comment: if you want to take 3, you can add ->take(3) before pluck.

Comment: I've tried it $queries = DB::table ....

and foreach ($queries as $query)
        {
            $results[] = ['id' => $query->id_adresse, 'value' => $query->libelle_adresse]; 
        }
        return response()->json($results);

but no result

Comment: Dnt add the foreach to it it bn done for use by the pluck

Comment: You can dd de result. Change de select to ->select ("libelle_address,id_address") since you are not using id

Comment: But I have to send the repense in form of json for the autocomplete jquery function

Comment: sorry i just looked at the foreach part. updating the code. change pluck to get and using alias on the select. now i think you should get what you want

Comment: Yeah that's right i think i have one more problem is the $_get['arrondis'] what you think about it in my question

Comment: I would rely on the Request object since $_GET is too old school php. So would change it it to $request->input('arrondis') or $request->arrondis. Please aacept and vote the answer if it help you. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you are showing if far more complex than what you need.

```
SELECT distinct libelle_adresse 
FROM adresse as a
INNER JOIN zone_address as za ON a.id_adresse = za.id_adress
INNER JOIN zone as z ON za.fk_zone = z.id_zone
INNER JOIN arrondissement as arr ON arr.id_arrondissement = z.id_arrondissement
Where libelle_arrondissement="'.$_GET['arrondis'].'")))
```

Since i don't have the table structure detail i might have make mistake in the labels i used in front of field. But this request is doing the same and is easier to handle.

Since documentation on laravel join is quite full of example. I hope this will be enough to help you.